# How do I pass data values from a particular column or field in a database into a variable in java?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Is there a way to pass data values for a `MySQL` database into a variable in `Java`?
This is what I have tried so far:

```
try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Login", "root", "****");
        String query = "Select username, passphrase from student where username=?";
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
        if (resultSet.next()) {
            _name = resultSet.getString(2);
            _pass_phrase = resultSet.getString(3);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
        assert resultSet != null;
        resultSet.close();
        statement.close();
    }
```

but I keep on getting a `NullPointerException` that points to my `_name` variable, telling me it empty. Could someone please point out to me what it is doing, and how to correct it?

Comment: I can see two issues, the first is that you don't set your username parameter, which would be something like `statement.setString(1, "Username")`, the second is that your result set only has two columns, and you are trying to retrieve columns 2 and 3, rather than 1 and 2.

Comment: Also (a) there should be no need to use `Class.forName();` except in some relatively uncommon scenarios (and in out-of-date tutorials). JDBC drivers register themselves. And (b) Don't use `statement.executeQuery(query);` here, just use `statement.executeQuery();`. The `query` (which is a Java String) has already been handled by `connection.prepareStatement(query)`. Don't use it again when you execute the statement.

Comment: There are lots of good JDBC answers on Stack Overflow showing how to use prepared statements to execute SELECTs, With some research you should find them.

Comment: @GarethD, I tried the solution you suggested but I still couldn't resolve the issue.

Comment: @KB21 Have you tried debugging and stepping through your code to see if you are ever reaching `_name = resultSet.getString(2);`? If I had to guess your select statement returns no records, therefore `resultSet.next()` returns false, so you never actually assign `_name`, so it remains null. That is of course a guess, because I have no idea what data sits in your `student` table, nor do I know what username you are using to get this error.